# Add/Remove Cache as filter on Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for a Cache filter which can be removed when certain action is performed.
Suppose

I have Index action which is loading records and cached with a filter for a minute.
As long as I am calling Index the action must be cached and no trip to db.

Once I create a record in Create action than it should remove the cache a load the records from DB.

Is there any solution to that.
I have found one in Ninject web example which is like below. I am looking for same solution.

```
[Cache(0, 0, 5, 0)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //Code here....
}

[HttpPost]
[ClearCacheOnSuccess("Index")]
public ActionResult Create(string confirmButton, CreateViewModel userVm)
{
    //Code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on where your cache is persisted (server or client) you could use the [RemoveOutputCacheItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/914c7ktw.aspx) method:

```
var urlToRemove = Url.Action("Index", "Home");
Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem(urlToRemove);
```